# Multivariate Lyapunov CLT?

Tags: central-limit-theorem

The univariate version of the Lyapunov CLT (a version of the CLT for independent but not necessarily iid random variables) is as follows according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Lyapunov_CLT):

[image: Lyapunov CLT from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Multidimensional_CLT]

Is there a multivariate version of the Lyapunov CLT (ideally one that doesn't require the means of the random variables to all be zero vectors)? I'm having a very hard time finding any information on this, even on Google Scholar.

Comment: Your last paragraph is a little puzzling, because it suggests you are interested in a sequence of random *matrices*--that, after all, is what "means ... be[ing] zero matrices" implies.  Indeed, even in the univariate case what version of the CLT requires all variables to have zero means??

Comment: Sorry I meant zero vectors. I'll fix it.

Comment: I guess you are searching for this theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem
See the Multidimensional version.

Comment: I get a lot of results when I search for multivariate *Lindeberg* CLT. The univariate Lindberg condition is implied by the Lyapunov condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the multivariate version may follow from the [Cramér-Wold theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Wold_theorem). You have to check that the conditions stated in your question are satisfied on every possible linear combination of components of $\mathbf X_i$, so this seems to require suitable behaviour of the cumulative variances $s_n(\mathbf a)$ defined as $s_{n}(\mathbf a) = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathrm{Var} (\mathbf a^T \mathbf X_i)$.